# Google maps wont to show height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I use twitter bootstrap 3 and google maps but this code wont to show map height in %. When I use PX everything is ok.

```
<body onload="findMyCurrentLocation()">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</div>
```

and css:

```
#map_canvas {
              height:100%;
}
```

Comment: What do you want the map height to be a percentage of? The viewport height? Its parent element's height?

Comment: if you want set height as percentage you need to set a height of parent container.basically form your code parent container has no height.It gets height of it`s child container.So height:100% will not work as you wanted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
     <div id="map_canvas"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem comes from the fact that you didn't add a container.

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding a little explanation.

Comment: Thank-you @JasonAller I will improve my answer next time.